# WordPress Integration to existing database content for search and filtering

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, integration, taxonomy

I writing this to find out how I can use WordPress by describing my existing website and what my key requirements are.

I have an existing site written in PHP (Cakephp to be specific), where I have login-based merchants logging in keying in data. It's like an online business directory. So Merchants will be keying in their business categories (e.g. services, catering, cleaning, location, etc).

I want to build a public front end website (exploring use of WordPress) which allows the public to view, search, filter or categorize this data which already exists in my mysql database. Kind of the search and filter functions you find on the left hand margin or top margin of ecommerce sites like EBay. IMagine If i was a public users, I'd go to this online business directory to and filter services by location and category to find what I want.

How can I use wordpress to easily achieve a public website with such search functions, using the existing data in my mysql database?
- note I am not looking to build an ecommerce website,
- I just want the public to search /filter/categorize my existing mysql data)

Is there some way to integrate (I think its "taxonomy" I required?) WordPress with my existing mysql database content? Do I need to move everything entirely onto WordPress generated tables?

Hope someone can point me at some options and steps of this integration.

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You could create a module which runs on the site and then iframe it in the area which you want to display the output for from search query which has access to the database.
If you think this is a way to go I can elaborate show you an example.